# Why does Firefox blur the webpage when the Esc key is pressed three times?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keypress

On my Dell Latitude 3120 2-in-1 laptop Firefox blurs the webpage (and sometimes destroys the site layout doing so) for a few seconds when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> three times in a row and
closes the current tab and replaces it with a tab in my default search engine when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> four times in a row.
Has anyone an idea on why this happens?
By the way: it happens both on Windows and on Linux, both with the standard installation of Firefox. On Firefox-built-in sites it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem myself - it was a privacy function of the "Startpage.com" extension I had installed. It blurs the page so you can minimize the window and nothing important can be seen in the preview and one <kbd>Esc</kbd> click more it and closes the current tab and opens Startpage.com's search engine.
How I found out? I uninstalled the extension because it didn't really help me and I was decluttering my browser and suddenly the behaviour stopped.
And it didn't work on Firefox-built-in sites because extensions don't work on such sites.